# SwiftUI Textfield state change stopped working with iOS 15.4.1

Tags: ios, swiftui, state, textfield, ios-15.4.1

The following code has worked fine until iOS 15.4.1.  It simply enables a button next to a textfield after the value entered is greater than 100000.  It still works with 15.3.1 but stopped working with 15.4.1.  Any idea what was changed to prevent it from working?

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var woid:Int? = nil
        @State var showResults = false
        private var woidFormatter:NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.groupingSeparator = ""
            return formatter
        }()
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Work Order Lookup")) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Work Order Number", value: $woid, formatter: woidFormatter)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button("Lookup") {
                            
                            showResults.toggle()
                        }.buttonStyle(PurpleButton(disabled: (woid ?? 0) < 100000))
                            .disabled((woid ?? 0) < 100000)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    struct PurpleButton: ButtonStyle {
        let disabled:Bool
        let cardColor:Color = Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1))
        
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .padding()
                .background(disabled ? Color.gray : cardColor)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
        }
    }
```

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is too much code we can't see to be able to help.

Comment: @Yrb I added enough code to be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: iam curious, the sample code should work, also with the optional --> default value.

Comment: That code has worked since last November and it still works in the previous version of iOS.

Comment: yes i agree, whats the error message

Comment: @Yrb the work order is an Int.  I tested it by removing the optional and you're right it works but it was working with an optional before the iOS update.  I'll try changing it to a string, converting it to an int, and then making the comparison.  Am I to assume it was a bug before?

Comment: @saro. No error message.  It just was't updating the control state and therefore the button would never enable.  See fix below

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it worked before but the proper signature for using optionals is this one:

```
    @available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    public init<F>(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, value: Binding<F.FormatInput?>, format: F, prompt: Text? = nil) where F : ParseableFormatStyle, F.FormatOutput == String
```

Changing this line:

```
TextField("Work Order Number", value: $vm.woid, formatter: woidFormatter)
```

to this works

```
TextField("Work Order Number", value: $vm.woid, format: .number)
```

Comment: If its a change, it wasn't listed in the docs. Good catch!